# how I can linearize or simplify these complicated and non-linear constraints?

Tags: optimization, nonlinear-optimization, non-convex-optimization, linearization

I have some constraints which are in the form $$ \dfrac{x_{1}-x_{2}+x_{3}+\cdots+x_{n}}{(x_{i}-x_{j})^{2}+\cdots+(x_{l}-x_{k})^{2}}+\cdots+\dfrac{x_{1}+x_{2}-x_{3}+\cdots+x_{n}}{(x_{j}-x_{i})^{2}+\cdots+(x_{l}-x_{k})^{2}} < 0$$

i.e., linear in the top and quadratic in the diameters. I am wondering is there any way for simplifying or linearizing of these kinds of constraints?

For example in $R^{5}$ we have:
 $$(2ak-2bk+k+1)(c_{0}(\dfrac{1}{(c_{0}+a(c_{1}+c_{4})-b(c_{2}+c_{3}))^{2}}+\dfrac{1}{((e(c_{1}-c_{4})+d(c_{2}-c_{3})))^{2}})+(5k+1-c_{0})(\dfrac{2a}{((e(c_{1}-c_{4})+d(c_{2}-c_{3})))^{2}}-\dfrac{b}{(c_{0}+a(c_{1}+c_{4})-b(c_{2}+c_{3}))^{2}}))<0$$
where a, b, c k, are some parameter in $R^{5}$ and $c_{0},...,c_{4}$ are variables.

Comment: How many terms are in the sum on the left? What values do $i$, $j$, $k$, and $l$ take?

Comment: If the quadratic denominators are the same in all summands (as your sample suggests), you can simply leave it out and it all simplifies to $\sum x_i < 0$. Since that's probably not the case, we need more detail on the structure ;)

Comment: we have n variables, so i,j k ,... are indices from 1 to n. and we have \frac{n}{2}  terms.

Comment: @AlexR I can not leave them out because it changes the feasibility of points

Comment: Would I be right in thinking that, for the $i$th term's numerator, $x_{i+1}$ is negative?

Comment: @AdrianKeister what do you mean?

Comment: @shere I guessed as much, but can you please completely specify the (different) denominators in some way or explain by writing it down for e.g. $n=3$? It's hard to see how they would differ exactly.

Comment: @shere: I'm kinda trying to tease out the same thing AlexR is trying to tease out: we don't have enough terms to get the pattern.

Comment: @AlexR ok I will edit the question with smallest example which is in R^{4}

Comment: @shere Thanks. By the way: If you want to use TeX in the comments, use dollar signs (`$`) like this: $\mathbb R^4$